# Rails 5. Select common associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have 2 models, connected with has_many :through association.

```
service has_many :masters, through: :master_services
master has_many :services, through: :master_services
```

The reason I used HMT: is that I need to give some details to each master/service intersection, like price and duration.

Via AJAX I transmit into controller an array of service_ids, and I should return into my view an array of Masters, (important!) who provides all of the enlisted services.

What I have got now:

```
services = params[:service_ids] #get array of service_ids
@services = Service.where(id: services) #get array of arrays of services (mindblowing)
@masters = @services.map {|service| service.masters } #get master for each service

@masters.flatten! #transform array of arrays into a plain array
@masters.uniq! #I don't need repeats
```

But this @services = Service.where(id: services) returns all masters for these services. It is translated to SQL like

```
SELECT * FROM services WHERE id in ('5', '6', '7')
```

It gives some results, but not what I want to achieve. I need a list of masters, who is in each of these services, common for all of the services. So I need your help, dear community. I don't know, maybe there is a way to do it via ActiveRecord, or with some transformation of the resulting arrays.

**Explanation**

Master Josh provides services: Car washing (id 1), Neural surgery (id 2), Shrink (id 3).
Master Helen provides services: Shrink (id 3), Car washing (id 1), Body double (id 4).
Master Francois provices services: Shrink (id 3).

I want if Shrink is chosen, get all of the Masters. 
If Shrink AND Car washing are chosen, get only Josh and Helen, as they provide both services, and Francois doesn't.
If only the Car washing is chosen, then get the same array of Josh and Helen.
And, by any chance, if the Neural surgery and Body double are chosen, get none - none of these masters provides both services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive this like this also

```
master_ids = MasterService.where(service_id: services)
                          .map(&:master_id)
                          .uniq
masters = Master.where(id: master_ids)
```

**Update:**

In this way you can achieve the result you are looking for

```
services = params[:service_ids]
masters = Master.joins(:master_services).where("master_services.service_id": services)
@masters = masters.select {|master| (services - master.services.map(&:id)).empty? }
@masters.uniq
```

in this

```
masters.select {|master| (services - master.services.map(&:id)).empty? }
```

we are selecting masters who has all the services we are looking for,
for example, if we are looking for services = [1, 3]

Masters Shrink has services = [1, 2, 3] 
we are doing `services - master.services.map(&:id)`
which means [1, 3] - [1, 2, 3] = [] means empty. so we will select this master. because he has all services we are looking for.

Master Helen - [1, 3] - [3, 1, 4] = [] empty, we'll select.
Master Francois - [1, 3] - [3] = [1] not empty. we won't select.

Comment: It gives the same result. All the masters, who provides at least one of the services, not all of them.

Comment: Oh sorry, you want masters are there in every service?

Comment: Done, please take a look.

Comment: Gives an exception. I removed @ from @masters.select, and now it's working.. but no matter what is chosen, returns empty array. I don't get what (services - master.services.map(&:id)).empty? is, but seems it doesn't work... :(

Comment: masters contains all the masters associated with these master_services, but @masters is []

Comment: Bingo! services = services.map {|service| service.to_i} does it. My services array was array of strings. ActiveRecord did to_i by itself, I think, but the (services - master.services.map(&:id)) did not. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. added explanation. take a look. thanks.